# Gower distance with R

Tags: r, clustering, distance, mixed-type-data, gower-similarity

I have 17 numeric and 5 binary (0-1) variables, with 73 samples in my dataset. I know that the Gower distance is a good metric for datasets with mixed variables.

When I use daisy function in cluster package, with metric="gower" I don't want to standardize my numeric variables, bcs. they are already in percent (0.25, 0.35...).

I also don't want it, becuase I couldn't get any good results when I used this Gower distance matrix for clustering with pam {cluster}, and I thought this standardization process may cause bad results.

So, is there any way not to standardize?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual page for this function?  It documents an argument, `stand`, which seems designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, see what it says: "If not all columns of x are numeric, stand will be ignored and Gower's standardization (based on the range) will be applied in any case" so I think there is no way to stop standardization.

Comment: According to your question, all your variables *are* numeric. (A binary variable is numeric, too--unless you intentionally cast it as a factor. But why would you do that?)

Comment: I see. So you mean, no need to use Gower? Because I used "Manhattan" distance in "pam {cluster}" and I got good results, 5 clusters. When I use "Gower" I can not have any clusters.